# How does Google Chrome's Sandbox work?

Tags: google-chrome, security, internet-security, sandbox

I was reading some [articles](http://blog.chromium.org/2008/10/new-approach-to-browser-security-google.html) regarding Google Chrome's sandbox and watched a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29e0CtgXZSI) but I don't have quite a full understanding of it. I read somewhere that it depends on Windows for its security so does that mean sandboxing for Google Chrome isn't used in Mac OS or Linux? I just wanted some clarification on this. Thanks.

Comment: "I read somewhere that it depends on Windows for its security" is true on Windows. If you read some more, you'll find that Chrome is sandboxed in Linux as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides Windows, Chrome's Sandbox is also used in [MacOS](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sandbox/osx-sandboxing-design) and [Linux](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSandboxing).

It is using different strategies according to the OS in which it is running.